# Why does this template argument deduction fail when a default value is given?

Tags: c++, templates

The following code works:

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    template <typename OStream>
    static void default_print_function(OStream &, const T &);

    template <typename OStream, typename PrintFunction>
    void print(
        OStream &,
        const PrintFunction & = &Foo<T>::default_print_function<OStream>) const;

    template <typename OStream>
    void print(OStream &) const;
};


template <typename T>
template <typename OStream>
void Foo<T>::default_print_function(OStream & o, const T & value)
{
    o << value;
}

template <typename T>
template <typename OStream, typename PrintFunction>
void Foo<T>::print(OStream & o, const PrintFunction & f)
const
{
    T test_value = 123;

    o << "TEST: ";
    f(o, test_value);
}

template <typename T>
template <typename OStream>
void Foo<T>::print(OStream & o)
const
{
    print(o, &default_print_function <OStream>);
}

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Foo <int> foo;

    foo.print(std::cerr, &Foo<int>::default_print_function<std::ostream>);
    std::cerr << std::endl;

    foo.print(std::cerr);
    std::cerr << std::endl;
}
```

However, if I comment out the `void print (OStream &) const` overload:

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    template <typename OStream>
    static void default_print_function(OStream &, const T &);

    template <typename OStream, typename PrintFunction>
    void print(
        OStream &,
        const PrintFunction & = &Foo<T>::default_print_function<OStream>) const;

    template <typename OStream>
    void print(OStream &) const;
};


template <typename T>
template <typename OStream>
void Foo<T>::default_print_function(OStream & o, const T & value)
{
    o << value;
}

template <typename T>
template <typename OStream, typename PrintFunction>
void Foo<T>::print(OStream & o, const PrintFunction & f)
const
{
    T test_value = 123;

    o << "TEST: ";
    f(o, test_value);
}

/*template <typename T>
template <typename OStream>
void Foo<T>::print(OStream & o)
const
{
    print(o, &default_print_function <OStream>);
}*/

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Foo <int> foo;

    foo.print(std::cerr, &Foo<int>::default_print_function<std::ostream>);
    std::cerr << std::endl;

    foo.print(std::cerr);
    std::cerr << std::endl;
}
```

Then it won't compile:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:54:25: error: no matching function for call to ‘Foo<int>::print(std::ostream&)’
  foo .print (std :: cerr);
                         ^
test.cpp:8:7: note: candidate: template<class OStream, class PrintFunction> void Foo<T>::print(OStream&, const PrintFunction&) const [with OStream = OStream; PrintFunction = PrintFunction; T = int]
  void print (
       ^~~~~
test.cpp:8:7: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:54:25: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘PrintFunction’
  foo .print (std :: cerr);
```

The default value for the second argument for `print` is spelled in a way which seems to me to be exactly equivalent to the way it is spelled in the first invocation in the `main` function.

```
foo .print (std :: cerr, & Foo <int> :: default_print_function <std :: ostream>);
```

So why can the template argument be deduced in this invocation, but not be deduced in the default argument

```
const PrintFunction & = & Foo <T> :: default_print_function <OStream>
```

?

Comment: Do you mind if I edit this to remove the spaces between the template parameters and the types and the scope operators?  It's really throwing me off as is.

Comment: @NathanOliver I would support throwing this into e.g. godbolt, letting its autoformatter run and pasting the code back into the question. The excessive spaces make this unreadable.

Comment: The template parameter is non-deducible, and the 2nd template parameter is completely unnecessary. Just declare it as `template <typename OStream>
    void print (
        OStream &,
 void (*PrintFunction)(OStream &, const T &)
        = & Foo <T> :: default_print_function <OStream>) const;`. I'm too lazy to look up the relevant cites from the standard, otherwise I'd post this as a complete answer. Be my guest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a non-deduced context:

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction)

> Non-deduced contexts:
>
> ...
>
> 4) A template parameter used in the parameter type of a function
>   parameter that has a default argument that is being used in the call
>   for which argument deduction is being done

**EDIT** (why it is a non-deduced context)

Because non-deduced context has a benefit: it allows the type to be used if it could be obtained from elsewhere.

Consider this example:

```
template<class T>
void foo(T, T = 1.0) {};

int main() {
    foo(2);
}
```

This is valid code. But if it were not a non-deduced context, the deduction would conflict. It's somewhat reasonable to assume the programmer want to have a conversion instead of a failure.

On the other hand, the type is essentially given elsewhere (default argument that is given at declaration). For example, your code will be fine if you `decltype` to the template parameter:

```
template <typename OStream, typename PrintFunction = decltype(&Foo<T>::default_print_function<OStream>)>
```

All in all, we lose nothing to make it a non-deduced context. Moreover, we make the conversion of default argument type possible when the type is supplied elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you. Since it seems to me that this *should* be deducible, can you explain why it actually isn't, other than by fiat?